History Field Tracking - Reports / Object - Task
I have a question: a client is asking me to track many task fields for audit purposes.

According to what I saw in the documentation, in the task object, you can track up to 6 fields.
Additionally, they request the ability to create reports, an option that also doesn't appear as standard in Salesforce.

What path do you suggest I follow to solve this? Perhaps build a custom object and transfer the data from the standard object to the custom one, so that it allows me to track more fields and also report on it?
I understand that this would require quite a bit of work, but I'm open to suggestions if you have any ideas. Thank you in advance! Regards!

Use the Activities report type to report on Tasks (and/or Events). Where do you see doc that only 6 fields can be tracked?

I got the information from Salesforce's official documentation: here is the link. There it says: "Event and Task History Considerations
It can take up to a few minutes for changes to appear in history.
You can track up to six fields on events or tasks".
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5.

TIL - the 6 field limit on Task/Event; true even if you license the add on Shield product that increases the limit from 20->60 on other objects.

Given the limit on field history (6) tracking on Task, which is true even if you license the Shield add-on that increases normal field history tracking from 20 to 60 fields, what I would consider is:

Retain use of the Task object. It is supported by the entire ecosystem of AppExchange partners and is displayed in a nice way in the Activity Timeline component of a Lightning Record page

Create a custom field Text Area (long) on Task called Change_Log__c.

Create a Custom metadata type to enumerate the Task fields you want to track history

Write a before Update Apex trigger on Task that reads the custom metadata for the field tokens to be checked for change.  If changed in the transaction, append to the value of Change_Log__c the date, running user name, before value and after value


So, for any given Task, you can see in one field the entire change history

Thank you very much. I will try to follow your advice!
